# Functor instance for Data.AVL

Tags: parameters, functor, agda

I would like to define a functor instance for `Data.AVL.Indexed.Tree`. This seems to be tricky because of the way the type `Key⁺` of the indices storing the upper and lower bounds of the tree "depend on" the type (or family of types) of the values in the tree.

What I want to do is implement `fmap` below:

```
open import Relation.Binary
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

module Temp
   {k ℓ}
   {Key : Set k}
   {_<_ : Rel Key ℓ}
   (isStrictTotalOrder : IsStrictTotalOrder _≡_ _<_) where

open import Function

module AVL (Value : Set)
   where open import Data.AVL (const Value) isStrictTotalOrder public

open AVL

fmap : {A B : Set} → (A → B) → ∀ {l u h} → 
       Indexed.Tree A l u h → Indexed.Tree B {!!} {!!} {!!}
fmap f = {!!}
```

For now I'm ignoring dependently-typed trees, and instead assuming the values have a constant type. The idea is to create a local variant of the `AVL` module, parameterised only on a type `Value`, and instantiate that at different types in order to give the signature of `fmap`.

The problem is that I then don't seem to be able to quantify over the bounds `l` and `u` in such a way that I can pass the *same* bounds to two different instances of `Indexed.Tree`. I think I see why this is: there are two different `Key⁺` types, one for `Indexed.Tree A` and one for `Indexed.Tree B`. But I want these types to be the same.

Am I missing something obvious here, or is `Data.AVL` just not parameterised in way that allows me to define `fmap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing anything obvious here. Even though `Key⁺` ignores the `Value` parameter, Agda still treats them as a different types. However, you can write the conversion functions quite easily. I'll open some modules to keep the names bearable:

```
open Extended-key
open Height-invariants

open import Data.Nat
```

Moving the `Key⁺` is very easy, since the underlying `Key`s are the same:

```
to : ∀ {A B} → Key⁺ A → Key⁺ B
to ⊥⁺    = ⊥⁺
to ⊤⁺    = ⊤⁺
to [ k ] = [ k ]
```

Moving the `_<⁺_` relation is also doable, you just need to pattern match on both `Key⁺`s so that the type is reduced to (basically) identity:

```
to< : ∀ {A B} l u → _<⁺_ A l u → _<⁺_ B (to l) (to u)
to< ⊥⁺   ⊥⁺     p = p
to< ⊥⁺   ⊤⁺     p = p
to< ⊥⁺   [ _ ]  p = p
to< ⊤⁺    _     p = p
to< [ _ ] ⊥⁺    p = p
to< [ _ ] ⊤⁺    p = p
to< [ _ ] [ _ ] p = p
```

Now, it might seem that this should do the trick, but when you try to write it down, you'll soon find out you need a way to transport the balance as well. Again, nothing extraordinary:

```
to∼ : ∀ {A B h₁ h₂} → _∼_ A h₁ h₂ → _∼_ B h₁ h₂
to∼ ∼+ = ∼+
to∼ ∼0 = ∼0
to∼ ∼- = ∼-
```

The type of `fmap` then looks like this:

```
fmap : ∀ {A B} (f : ∀ {x} → A x → B x) {l u h} →
       Indexed.Tree A l u h → Indexed.Tree B (to l) (to u) h
```

It's not a "true" `fmap`, but considering you need to have different `Key⁺`s, this is as close as we can get.

`leaf` case requires usage of `to<`, but is otherwise trivial:

```
fmap f {lb} {ub} (Indexed.leaf l<u) = Indexed.leaf (to< lb ub l<u)
```

`node` case is where things get interesting. The obvious solution:

```
fmap f (Indexed.node (k , v) l r bal) =
  Indexed.node (k , f v) (fmap f l) (fmap f r) (to∼ bal)
```

does not typecheck. Let's figure out why. Here are the types of the expression above and the goal type:

```
-- Have:
Indexed.Tree .B (to .l) (to .u) (suc (max .B (to∼ bal)))

-- Goal:
Indexed.Tree .B (to .l) (to .u) (suc (max .A bal))
```

So we need one extra proof:

```
max≡ : ∀ {A B} {h₁ h₂} (bal : _∼_ A h₁ h₂) →
  max A bal ≡ max B (to∼ bal)
max≡ ∼+ = refl
max≡ ∼0 = refl
max≡ ∼- = refl
```

And finally, we can rewrite the goal type via `max≡ bal` and get the desired implementation:

```
fmap f (Indexed.node (k , v) l r bal) rewrite max≡ bal =
  Indexed.node (k , f v) (fmap f l) (fmap f r) (to∼ bal)
```

---

I'm also using the more dependent variant of the tree. This is done by defining `AVL` module as:

```
import Data.AVL
module AVL (Value : Key → Set)
  = Data.AVL Value isStrictTotalOrder
```

And then simply requiring the mapping function to respect the `Key` value:

```
mapping-function : {A B : Key → Set} {x : Key} → A x → B x
```

---

There's another option: rewrite the `Data.AVL` module such that `Extended-key` and `Height-invariants` are not parametrised by `Value`. While this requires a change in the standard library, I think it's the better solution. `Extended-key` and `Heigh-invariants` could certainly be useful outside of `Data.AVL` - in fact, I have a `Data.BTree` that uses exactly that.

If you decide to go this way, consider separating them into new modules (such as `Data.ExtendedKey`) and submitting a patch/pull request.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I didn't even think of mapping the types and their operations in that way. But yes, the fact that one ends up with something that is not a true `fmap` isn't ideal.

I'm inlined towards sucking out `Extended-key` and `Height-invariants` into a separate module. (I'm also reusing `Extended-key` for the `FiniteMap` data type I mentioned recently, and it would indeed be more convenient that way.)

Perhaps this should be a separate question, but I wonder also whether the ordering constraints for `Data.AVL.Indexed.Tree` could be made proof-irrelevant at the same time?

Comment: I had a very quick look at proof-irrelevance (for the l<u bound on a leaf) and got the impression that it would be possible, with minor changes to `headTail` and `initLast`. (But I haven't tried it properly yet.) Anyway, thanks again for an excellent answer.

Comment: @Roly: About the `Extended-key`, I actually made a module like that some time ago. Figured you might find it useful: https://gist.github.com/vituscze/8673269

Comment: Thanks. I also implemented something like your `IsStrictTotalOrder` instance, although I didn't bother parameterising on an arbitrary equality because I've moved away from that style in my own development. But yeah, it seems nicer to show that the strict total orders are closed under the functor (+ 2) than simply show that transitivity is preserved, as in `Data.AVL.Extended-key`.