# Data.AVL.map that changes value type

Tags: dictionary, functor, agda

The [`Data.AVL` module of the standard library](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.AVL.html) is parametrized by the value type (among other things):

```
module Data.AVL
  {k v ℓ}
  {Key : Set k} (Value : Key → Set v)
  {_<_ : Rel Key ℓ}
  (isStrictTotalOrder : IsStrictTotalOrder _≡_ _<_)
```

which of course means the `map` function it exports can't change the value type:

```
map : ({k : Key} → Value k → Value k) → Tree → Tree
```

Is there a way still to transform values stored in a `Tree` in a non-endomorphic way?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369719/functor-instance-for-data-avl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have performed [the refactoring](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/pull/183) I was suggesting in the comment to @JannisLimperg's answer. <strike>You can readily access it in the [refactor-avl branch of the standard library](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/tree/refactor-avl).</strike> Edit: **it's been merged and is now part of the stdlib!**

Here is the summary of the changes as listed in the changelog:

#### Overhaul of `Data.AVL`

- Splitting out `Data.AVL.Key` and `Data.AVL.Height` which should not depend
  on the type of `Value` the tree will contain.
- Putting `Indexed` into its own core module `Data.AVL.Indexed` following the
  example of e.g. `Category.Monad.Indexed` or `Data.Container.Indexed`
- Giving `map` a polymorphic type: it is now possible to change the type of
  values contained in a tree when mapping over it.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, this seems to be if not impossible then at least very annoying. The internal tree representation, `Indexed.Tree`, is parameterised by upper and lower bounds of type `Key⁺ Value ...`, so one would have to convert between `Key⁺ V` and `Key⁺ W` for different value types `V, W` and convince Agda that the conversion doesn't change anything. (It doesn't, of course, since `Value` is not used in the definition of `Key⁺`, but proving this is a hassle.)

The easiest way to solve the problem would therefore be to fix the library, moving the `Value` parameter down a few scopes. I'm sure the Agda devs would accept a patch to that effect.

Comment: It may be worth refactoring the whole module, splitting it up into a bunch of files and have `Data.AVL.Key`, `Data.AVL.Indexed` and `Data.AVL`. Maybe even dig through the [multitude of SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Data.AVL+%5Bagda%5D) to identify the common pain points and remove them.